# Projections in properly infinite factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Denote by $\sim$ the "Murray-von Neumann" equivalence in the projection lattice of a von Numann algebra. Let $e$ be a projection in a properly infinite factor. Is it always true that $e\sim 1$ or $1-e\sim 1$?

Comment: Would you recall the meaning of $\sim$? (I'm not sure the downvote is appropriate, the language of von Neumann algebras always sounds weird since it uses words that are more or less meaningful in other contexts)

Comment: @YCor Thank you, I added the meaning of $\sim$.